# How can I make copies of a Stream so when it is used I use the duplicate in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is how my code looks :

```
public static String firstContainsChars(Stream<String> items,String charset) {
    char[] inChars = charset.toCharArray();
    for (char ch:inChars) {
        items.filter(s->s.contains(String.valueOf(ch)));
    }
    return items.findFirst().orElse("No Match Found");
}
```

In fact, I am getting a collection of chars as a `String` and `filter` the stream but the problem is I can't use the stream several times in the `foreach` loop and compiler says :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

Any ideas on how to duplicate the Stream without the need to collect it as a `Collection` as it will be total waste. (streaming and collecting after the chnage)?

Comment: You can pass a `Supplier<Stream<String>>` to your function.

Comment: @Flown, Thanks, A very simple code snippet on how to use it will be appreciated as I am a total newbie and don't know what to search in google.

Comment: A `Stream` has no memory, the only alternative to using a Collection which does have a memory is to re-evaluate the Stream each time.

Comment: To make your code work you should change the line in the loop to: `items = items.filter(s -> s.contains(String.valueOf(ch)));`

Comment: No, finding all strings who contain all of the charsets. For example for filtering out all items who have `a`,`b`,`c`, We should pass "abc" as the second argument.

Comment: @Flown, Thanks, It worked altogether!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed-java-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment section you have to assign `items` to the new pipeline in the loop.

```
public static String firstContainsChars(Stream<String> items, String charset) {
  char[] inChars = charset.toCharArray();
  for (char ch : inChars) {
    items = items.filter(s -> s.contains(String.valueOf(ch)));
  }
  return items.findFirst().orElse("No Match Found");
}
```

But a much cleaner approach would be to `Stream` your charset too, like:

```
public static String firstContainsChars(Stream<String> items, String charset) {
  return items.filter(s -> charset.codePoints().allMatch(cp -> s.indexOf(cp) != -1))
              .findFirst().orElse("No Match Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to duplicate the stream, just stream the charset chars inside your filter :

```
public static String firstContainsChars(Stream<String> items, String charset){

    return items
            .filter(s-> charset
                        .chars() // stream of all the chars in charset
                        .mapToObj(i -> (char)i ) //chars() is actually a stream of ints... convert to chars
                        .allMatch(c -> s.indexOf(c) >= 0) //check that all chars are contained in the string
            )
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("No Match Found");
}

List<String> items = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "foobar");

String s1 = firstContainsChars(items.stream(), "of");  // -> "foo"
String s2 = firstContainsChars(items.stream(), "rab"); // -> "bar"
String s3 = firstContainsChars(items.stream(), "fob"); // -> "foobar"
String s4 = firstContainsChars(items.stream(), "xyz"); // -> "No Match Found"
```

Comment: good solution but if you can avoid multiple lines inside `{}` in lambda will be much cleaner solution

Comment: @ehsan : basically the same as the second option from Flown's answer. You will get used to "think in streams" as you start using them more !

Comment: @AsteriskNinja : You are right, I removed the {} and return statment. However I think it is much more readable if you spread it on several lines

Answer (score 0):

I will not enter in goal of you efforts, but say that you code will doing nothing, because `filter` is just intermediate operation on stream, it is not terminate operation like `findFirst`.
Now, you can rewrite you code to see how it works like :

```
public static String firstContainsChars(Stream<String> items,String charset) {
    String result = "";
    char[] inChars = charset.toCharArray();
    for (char ch:inChars) {
      result = items.filter(s->s.contains(String.valueOf(ch))).findFirst().orElse("No Match Found");
      System.out.println(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But please, read documentation for understanding operations on stream and lifecycle of its https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps