# Reusing Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to calculate the ratio of two parts of the big List, wherein the first part contains the second:

```
Stream<Element> part1 = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getN1() < x.getN2);
int result = part1.filter(y -> y.isRight()).count() / part1.count();
```

But this code throws the Exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed**

Can I write a code without creating the same *part1* stream in *result*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reuse a collection as it has memoriation of results.

```
List<Element> part1 = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getN1() < x.getN2).collect(toList());
double result = (double) part1.stream().filter(y -> y.isRight()).count() / part1.size();
```

A Stream is a builder for some code which is optimised at run time. It's execution isn't as dynamic as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not supposed to be reused, or if you want something seemed to it, you can use suppliers as mentioned here : [Copy a stream to avoid "stream has already been operated upon or closed" (java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed-java-8)