# What is the most efficient way to make a copy of a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method which performs processing on a stream. Part of that processing needs to be done under the control of a lock - one locked section for processing all the elements - but some of it doesn't (and shouldn't be because it might be quite time-consuming). So I can't just say:

```
Stream<V> preprocessed = Stream.of(objects).map(this::preProcess);
Stream<V> toPostProcess;
synchronized (lockObj) {
    toPostProcess = preprocessed.map(this::doLockedProcessing);
}
toPostProcess.map(this::postProcess).forEach(System.out::println);
```

because the calls to `doLockedProcessing` would only be executed when the terminal operation `forEach` is invoked, and that is outside the lock.

So I think I need to make a copy of the stream, using a terminal operation, at each stage so that the right bits are done at the right time. Something like:

```
Stream<V> preprocessed = Stream.of(objects).map(this::preProcess).copy();
Stream<V> toPostProcess;
synchronized (lockObj) {
    toPostProcess = preprocessed.map(this::doLockedProcessing).copy();
}
toPostProcess.map(this::postProcess).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Of course, the `copy()` method doesn't exist, but if it did it would perform a terminal operation on the stream and return a new stream containing all the same elements.

I'm aware of a few ways of achieving this:

(1) Via an array (not so easy if the element type is a generic type):

```
copy = Stream.of(stream.toArray(String[]::new));
```

(2) Via a list:

```
copy = stream.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream();
```

(3) Via a stream builder:

```
Stream.Builder<V> builder = Stream.builder();
stream.forEach(builder);
copy = builder.build();
```

What I want to know is: which of these methods is the most efficient in terms of time and memory? Or is there another way which is better?

Comment: either 2 or 3 - I would go with 3 as it is a bit more idiomatic (to me)

Comment: Why either 2 or 3?

Comment: What is the type of `objects`?

Comment: In my real-world application, it's a generic type - it could be anything.

Comment: Related: [Copy a stream...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23860533/1371329)

Comment: Note that none of your options *copy* the stream, because your code *consumes* the original stream in order to make the new one, thus achieving nothing more than `copy = stream` and pointless processing.

Comment: this is the part that IMO you get wrong about streams in general *one locked section for processing all the elements* - you can't achieve that. Stream process elements one at a time, your `map` is executed for one element only, not all of them at once.

Comment: @JeremyHicks `objects` seems to be an array, as you pass it to `Stream.of`, so is it `V[]`? I’m asking, because your code does only contain `map` steps from `V` to `V`, which raises the question whether they are actually functions receiving a value and producing a value. The requirement of synchronizing one processing step speaks against it. So it looks much like you are actually doing a multi-step process over an array and the Stream API is by far the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have already mentioned all possible options. There's no other structural way to do what you need. First, you'd have to consume the original stream. Then, create a new stream, acquire the lock and consume this new stream (thus invoking your locked operation). Finally, create a yet newer stream, release the lock and go on processing this newer stream.

From all the options you are considering, I would use the third one, because the number of elements it can handle is only limited by memory, meaning it doesn't have an implicit max size restriction, like i.e. `ArrayList` has (it can contain about `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements).

Needless to say, this would be a quite expensive operation, both regarding time and space. You could do it was follows:

```
Stream<V> temp = Stream.of(objects)
        .map(this::preProcess)
        .collect(Stream::<V>builder,
                 Stream.Builder::accept,
                 (b1, b2) -> b2.build().forEach(b1))
        .build();

synchronized (lockObj) {
    temp = temp
            .map(this::doLockedProcessing)
            .collect(Stream::<V>builder,
                     Stream.Builder::accept,
                     (b1, b2) -> b2.build().forEach(b1))
            .build();
}

temp.map(this::postProcess).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that I've used a single `Stream` instance `temp`, so that intermediate streams (and their builders) can be garbage-collected, if needed.

---

As suggested by @Eugene in the comments, it would be nice to have a utility method to avoid code duplication. Here's such method:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> copy(Stream<T> source) {
    return source.collect(Stream::<T>builder,
                          Stream.Builder::accept,
                          (b1, b2) -> b2.build().forEach(b1))
                 .build();
}
```

Then, you could this method as follows:

```
Stream<V> temp = copy(Stream.of(objects).map(this::preProcess));

synchronized (lockObj) {
    temp = copy(temp.map(this::doLockedProcessing));
}

temp.map(this::postProcess).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I like this solution; under the hood it uses `SpinedBuffer` - a collection that is not exposed and used by Streams; I have not looked too much inside it, I just hope it is better to collect to it rather that an `ArrayList`. 1+

Comment: btw you could also update the code to provide a utility method that would generate a `Collector` that collects to a `Builder`

Comment: @Eugene a spined buffer is an array of arrays, so when a target array’s capacity is exhausted, a new array will be added to the outer array instead of replacing the array. So unlike `ArrayList`, it does not need to copy all contained elements when expanding. When the outer array’s capacity is exhausted, resizing it only needs cheap copying of the array references, but then you’re beyond the capacity of ordinary collections anyway. So doing random access would be more complicated, but that’s why it is not a `List`. `Stream.Builder` adds special support for empty and single element cases to it.

Comment: @Holger I should have read the documentation as it seems to touch exactly this...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I don’t know, perhaps they wanted to keep the possibility of refactoring this class in later versions. But is there anything you could do with it when having direct access, which you can’t do with `Stream.Builder`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner well, neither of them would work if `SpinedBuffer` was `public`, as that class does not support removal and there’s no way to add this functionality atop of it. You would have to implement that yourself anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I created a benchmark test which compares the three methods. This suggested that using a `List` as the intermediate store is about 30% slower than using an array or a `Stream.Builder`, which are similar. I am therefore drawn to using a `Stream.Builder` because converting to an array is tricky where the element type is a generic type.

I've ended up writing a little function that creates a `Collector` which uses a `Stream.Builder` as the intermediate store:

```
private static <T> Collector<T, Stream.Builder<T>, Stream<T>> copyCollector()
{
    return Collector.of(Stream::builder, Stream.Builder::add, (b1, b2) -> {
        b2.build().forEach(b1);
        return b1;
    }, Stream.Builder::build);
}
```

I can then make a copy of any stream `str` by doing `str.collect(copyCollector())` which feels quite in keeping with the idiomatic usage of streams.

The original code I posted would then look like this:

```
Stream<V> preprocessed = Stream.of(objects).map(this::preProcess).collect(copyCollector());
Stream<V> toPostProcess;
synchronized (lockObj) {
    toPostProcess = preprocessed.map(this::doLockedProcessing).collect(copyCollector());
}
toPostProcess.map(this::postProcess).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I find it weird to "collect" to a `Stream`. I would collect to a `Builder` instead, but it is just me... Also I am not sure about that `Characteristics.UNORDERED`, it seems it should not be present. Otherwise, not a bad solution at all, 1+

Comment: Collecting to a `Builder` would work equally well, but it just puts the responsibility of calling `build()` on the client which seems unnecessary. I included `Characteristics.UNORDERED` because as far as I can see, there is no way of guaranteeing the order of the output stream if the combiner (for combining two intermediate builders) is called.

Comment: that is the point when you merge like this, the order will be preserved. Some people call `b1/b2` `left/right` to denote that

Comment: OK thank you, I understand now. I thought that you couldn't predict anything about the subsets of the data that would be merged using any particular call to the combiner, but it appears that you can: they will always be derived from adjacent subsets of the source stream. in which case, the collector as written does guarantee order. I'll remove the `Characteristics.UNORDERED`.

Comment: *adjacent subsets of the source stream* - not always, you could have an `ArrayList` as source, but call `unordered/sorted` on it - and thus loose the initial order...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `doLockedProcessing` it in synchronization. Here’s one way:

```
class SynchronizedFunction<T, R> {
    private Function<T, R> function;
    public SynchronizedFunction(Function<T, R> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
    public synchronized R apply(T t) {
        return function.apply(t);
    }
}
```

Then use that in your stream:

```
stream.parellel()
  .map(this:preProcess)
  .map(new SynchronizedFunction<>(this::doLockedProcessing))
  .forEach(this::postProcessing)
```

This will serially process the locked code, but be parellel otherwise.

Comment: isn't this the same thing I proposed (but it seems it is still not what the OP wants)? This will indeed create a single instance of `SynchronizedFunction`, but for each element of the stream, `apply` will be called, which is `synchronized`, so for each element, that lock will be tried. What OP wants is acquire the lock (once) and execute all the elements under that lock. I don't think that is possible

Comment: @Eugene, you're correct. This will establish a separate lock for each element of the stream. I want the processing of all the elements to be done in one lock.