# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this snippet:

```
    final Stream<String>stream = getStream().filter(a->StringUtils.contains(a,"http"));
    stream.filter(a->true);//LINE PROBLEM I JUST THOUGHT THAT THIS WOULD  JUST IGNORE
    System.out.println(stream.count());
```

But throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

I know that streams can be used just once but what is wrong with this line? It's consuming the stream?

```
stream.filter(a->true);//NOT A TERMINAL OPERATION A INTERMEDIATE OPERATION
```

If I ripped it of just use my code like this

```
System.out.println(stream.filter(a->true).count());
```

Not exception is thrown.

If I use this code NotException is Thrown.

```
    Stream<String>stream = getStream().filter(a->StringUtils.contains(a,"http"));
    stream = stream.filter(a->true);
    System.out.println(stream.count());
```

But why filter is throwing exception and **IS NOT A TERMINAL OPERATION**?

I am using just the simplest code to get the idea.

I am using Netbeans 8.2 with Java 8 update 122 also tested in Intellij Idea 2018 Ultimate.

Comment: Is this request stream?  OverrideHttpinputmessage  and httpmessageconverter and then use IOUtils.toString() to convert stream as string then use lambda expression.

Comment: is just a example.. to represent the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) javadoc:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

To avoid this, you can use [`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html)

See also [Copy a stream to avoid "stream has already been operated upon or closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed)

Comment: hi but filter is not a terminal operation why is this exception thrown?

Comment: @chiperortiz it doesn't matter. See the first sentence from doc: _(invoking an **intermediate** or **terminal** stream operation)_

Comment: awesome best regards pal.