# Validate a string using java 8 Stream. How to overcome "stream has already been operated upon or closed"?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-stream

The task is to check using Stream if such type of string "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130" satisfies these conditions:

1. 20 uppercase alphabetical chars or digits before the space, the number of digits is 6 strictly
2. 6 digits after the space

Here is what I've done so far:

```
    public static boolean validateCode(String input)
{
    String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));

    Stream<Character> left = wordList.get(0).chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch);
    Stream<Character> right = wordList.get(1).chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch);

   boolean leftIs20 = left
            .collect(Collectors.counting()).equals(20L);

    boolean leftisAlfaDigit = left
            .allMatch(x -> (Character.isDigit(x) || Character.isUpperCase(x)));

     boolean leftis6Digits = left.filter(x -> Character.isDigit(x)).equals(6L);

    boolean rightAreDigits = right.allMatch(x ->Character.isDigit(x));

    boolean rightAre6Digits = right.collect(Collectors.counting()).equals(6L);
    
    return leftIs20 && leftisAlfaDigit && leftis6Digits && rightAreDigits && rightAre6Digits;
}
```

But as a stream cannot be reused, it is wrong, but I have no idea how to overcome the issue.

Comment: Related question: [Copy a stream to avoid “stream has already been operated upon or closed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860533/copy-a-stream-to-avoid-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed)

Comment: You could create again the stream each time... but using regexp would be much simpler for such a task

Comment: I would suggest not using streams, the code is not readable, there are most likely easier and better ways to achieve that logic. At least for the length calculations - why would use a stream for that??

Comment: @luk2302 that's the task - to use stream

Comment: @geocodezip thanks! Yes, I saw it, but as I've just started to learn java, I didn't get how can I apply it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out it's not necessary to use streams for this but it can be done. If I understood the requirements correctly then this should satisfy what you're after with streams.

```
  private static boolean validateCode(String in) {
    //The task is to check using Stream if such type of string "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130" satisfies these conditions:
    //20 uppercase alphabetical chars or digits before the space, the number of digits is 6 strictly
    //6 digits after the space
    final var input = in.split("\\s");
    final var a = input[0];
    final var b = input[1];
    return a.chars().filter(c -> Character.isDigit(c) || (Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c))).count() == 20 &&
      b.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == 6;
  }
```

To test it:

```
    System.err.println(validateCode("AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130")); //valid
    System.err.println(validateCode("Z6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130")); //less than 20
    System.err.println(validateCode("A$6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130")); //non alpha numeric
    System.err.println(validateCode("AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284k30")); //non-digit in end
    System.err.println(validateCode("AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 28413")); //less than 6
    System.err.println(validateCode("AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 2841302")); //more than 6
```

**EDIT - I missed the fact the first part must have 6 digits**

```
  private static boolean validateCode(String in) {
    final var input = in.split("\\s");
    final var a = input[0];
    final var b = input[1];
    final var prefixCounts = a.chars()
      .mapToObj(c -> Map.entry(Character.isDigit(c) ? 1 : 0, Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 1 : 0))
      .reduce(Map.entry(0, 0), (lhs, rhs) -> Map.entry(lhs.getKey() + rhs.getKey(), lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue()));
    return prefixCounts.getKey() == 6 && prefixCounts.getValue() == 14 && //6 digits and 14 upper case letters = 20 total
      b.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == 6;
  }
```

I will caution that using this will work but the stream API is probably overkill. This solution also creates temporary objects during the map-reduce that could be avoided with other solutions. It's not a big deal for many cases but in a performance critical situation this could show up in profiling. You'd have to see how it compares to a regex or other solution in your own tests. This just answers the question using the approach requested.

Comment: The left part must have 6 digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is so elegant!

Comment: @LiveandLetLive, thank you for your notice! I managed to do it just adding one line `&& a.chars().filter(c -> Character.isDigit(c)).count() == 6`

Comment: @EvgeniyKravtsov - yes that's one way to do it. If you want to only iterate over a once you can use the edited solution which transforms the stream to counts then reduces to get a final count of characters matching the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to match patterns so streams is not necessary or really appropriate.  But, you can do it with  a single stream using a `filter`

```
String[] data = { "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130",  // valid
                 "AZ6BYW59UO6&C8BNT7NM 2841S0",   // non letter or digit (&)             
        "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM 823820",            // not enough digits
        "111111MMMMMMMMMMMMMM 228130",            // valid
        "11111111111111111111 228130",            // too may digits
        "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BT7NM 284130",             // first word too short
        "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 2824130",           // seven digits
        "AZ6BYW59UO6CRs8BNT7NM 284130",           // first word too long
        "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM    282230"          // too many spaces
    "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 28230" };               // five digits



for (String text : data) {
    System.out.printf("%30s -> %s%n", text, validateCode(text) ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
}
```

Prints

```
   AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130 -> Valid
   AZ6BYW59UO6&C8BNT7NM 2841S0 -> Invalid
   MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM 823820 -> Invalid
   111111MMMMMMMMMMMMMM 228130 -> Valid
   11111111111111111111 228130 -> Invalid
    AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BT7NM 284130 -> Invalid
  AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 2824130 -> Invalid
  AZ6BYW59UO6CRs8BNT7NM 284130 -> Invalid
AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM    282230 -> Invalid
    AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 28230 -> Invalid
```

This splits on a single space and and the tries to match the required contents.  If it gets thru, the count will be 1 and true will be returned.  Otherwise, 0 and false.

- `\\w{20}` will match a word of 20 letters and digits.
- `\\d{6}` will match a number of 6 digits.

```
public static boolean validateCode(String text) {
    return Stream.<String[]>of(text.split("\\s"))
            .filter(s -> s.length == 2 && s[0].matches("\\w{20}") && s[0].chars()
                    .filter(Character::isDigit)
                    .count() == 6 && s[1].matches("\\d{6}"))
            .count() == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you check the size of the resulting array (i.e. the array obtained by splitting the given string) to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
2. Since you have to perform three independent operations on the left side of the substring, you will have to create a stream-supplier to construct a new stream with all intermediate operations already set up. Check [this article](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) to learn more about it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrs = { "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130", "AZ6BYW59UOXCR8BNT7NM 284130",
                "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 7284130", "AbZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130", "AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM284130" };
        for (String s : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + validateCode(s));
        }
    }

    public static boolean validateCode(String input) {
        int leftAllCount = 20, leftDigCount = 6, rightDigCount = 6;
        String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
        if (words.length >= 2) {
            Supplier<Stream<Character>> streamSupplierLeft = () -> words[0].chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch);
            Stream<Character> right = words[1].chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch);
            return streamSupplierLeft.get().count() == leftAllCount
                    && streamSupplierLeft.get().filter(Character::isDigit).count() == leftDigCount
                    && streamSupplierLeft.get().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count() == (leftAllCount - leftDigCount)
                    && right.filter(Character::isDigit).count() == rightDigCount;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130 => true
AZ6BYW59UOXCR8BNT7NM 284130 => false
AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 7284130 => false
AbZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM 284130 => false
AZ6BYW59UO6CR8BNT7NM284130 => false
```